# (AUTHOR1 & AUTHOR2, YEAR)

Tags: citing, ampersand, type

I'm using `abntex2cite` and when I write `\cite{...}` with a reference that has two authors, the result is (AUTHOR1; AUTHOR2, YEAR). What can I do to appear (AUTHOR1 & AUTHOR2, YEAR)? I've already tried:

```
\usepackage[abnt-and-type=&,abnt-etal-text=it,abnt-etal-cite=2,abnt-etal-list=0,alf]{abntex2cite}
```

But it didn't work. Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try `abnt-and-type={\&}`.

Comment: If you are only looking for citation/bibliography style from ABNT, you might be interested in [`biblatex-abnt`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt?lang=en). With it you'd be able to achieve these customizations with more standard biblatex's options.

Comment: Hi Phelype. The command abnt-and-type={\&} didn't work, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi Gusbrs, thanks for answer, but I really need to use & because my professor is a little mad.

Comment: @Celougly, the fact that your professor is a bit mad doesn't mean he's right about ABNT rules, and doesn't mean he knows Latex at all, and doesn't mean it makes any difference. As gusbrs said, it's easier to use `biblatex-abnt`, but it's up to you to make it please your advisor. Maybe if you contact the `biblatex-abnt` author on github or the google discussion list you'll have a prompt answer.